# APEX -- Error on custom lead conversion code!

Tags: apex, deployment

I have an APEX code that will convert Leads (it's triggered at the conclusion of a flow):

```
trigger CustomLeadConversion on Lead (after insert,after update) {
     LeadStatus convertStatus = [
          select MasterLabel
          from LeadStatus
          where IsConverted = true
          limit 1
     ];
     List<Database.LeadConvert> leadConverts = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();

     for (Lead lead: Trigger.new) {
          if (!lead.isConverted && lead.Custom_Lead_Conversion__c == TRUE) {
               Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
               String oppName = lead.Name + 'Deal';

               lc.setLeadId(lead.Id);
               lc.setOpportunityName(oppName);
               lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);

               leadConverts.add(lc);
          }
     }

     if (!leadConverts.isEmpty()) {
          List<Database.LeadConvertResult> lcr = Database.convertLead(leadConverts);
     }
}
```

When attempting to deploy, I run into this error message:

> System.QueryException: No such column 'OtherAddress' on entity
>   'Contact'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to
>   append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your
>   WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

I am completely lost... OtherAddress is a SFDC default field...

Comment: not sure if this is related, but as suggested in this known issue  https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T3FOAA0            if ur API version is before 29, can u change it and see if it fixes the error

Comment: Hi Vamsi, API version is set to 34 for this code. So this might not be the case..